# How to Include a common category in a custom Category Search

Tags: posts, categories, wp-query

I was wondering how to solve this issue.

This is my Query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
   'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'category__not_in' => array( 7, 22 ) ) );
```

This is a simple query, What it does is queries all the recent posts and excludes the posts having category IDs 7 and 22.

I have some posts which have two categories linked to it, like, "7 and 10" and "22 and 13". above query excludes these posts too (as it should be), but I also want the query to INCLUDE posts that have two or more categories - one of which might be 7 or 22. I was wondering is it possible?

I hope I've explained it. I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can express logic like this in query arguments and custom SQL will probably be nightmarish.

I would try to flip the logic. Declare `category__in` to be list of all categories, but the ones you don't want.

You can build such list by code, like:

```
'category__in' => get_categories( array( 'fields' => 'ids', 'exclude' => '7,22' ) ),
```

PS I am not sure about performance aspect of such query, depends on number of categories involved I guess. Test before using in production.

Comment: using `category__in` requires editing the code manually every time I create a new category. So best way is to write custom SQL query?

Comment: @WebWarrior why manually? you could build such list by code. I wouldn't even know where to start on SQL, "not this unless that" would be challenging as above

Comment: how do I list categories such that ? I appreciate your help on this. Thanks